# Trying to filter based on Date in R, receiving Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I am attempting to filter my dataframe to just dates within the fiscal year (10-01-2018 / 09-31-2019).

Thought this would be simplier but I keep recieving an error.

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Here's what I am trying:

Dataset:

```
toStata <- structure(list(`Advance Identifier` = c("A00010001", "A00010001", 
"A00010001", "A00010001", "A00010001"), `Date Due` = structure(c(1312934400, 
1317772800, 1325721600, 1333584000, 1341446400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Disbursement = c(85740440.38, 0, 0, 
0, 0), `Principal Due` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Interest Due` = c(0, 
425817.56, 699557.43, 691953.54, 691953.54), `Capitalized Interest Due` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `Repayment Timing` = c("Beginning", "Beginning", 
"Beginning", "Beginning", "Beginning"), `Disbursement Timing` = c("Beginning", 
"Beginning", "Beginning", "Beginning", "Beginning"), `Capitalized Interest` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Payment = c(0, 425817.56, 699557.43, 691953.54, 
691953.54), `Cash Grant Amount` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Cash Grant Prepayment Effect Principal` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `Cash Grant Prepayment Effect Interest` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `Cash Grant Prepayment Effect Capitalized Interest` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `Interest Rate` = c(0.03237, 0.03237, 0.03237, 0.03237, 
0.03237), `Payment Frequency` = c("Quarterly", "Quarterly", "Quarterly", 
"Quarterly", "Quarterly"), `Modification Principal` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Modification Interest` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Modification Capitalized Interest` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
library(tidyverse)
file <- toStata %>% 
  filter('Date Due' >= as.Date("2010-10-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d") & 'Date Due' <= as.Date("2011-09-31", format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Maybe I have too many details? Unsure, regardless I have recieved an error at every turn; any alternatives would be helpful!

Comment: @joran didn't work :/

Comment: @ah it workeD! bn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30 days have September, April, June & November... check your second date in `filter()`

Also, you need to use backticks if you have illegal characters (like spaces) in your variable names.